# How can a function handle multiple structs as result?

Tags: c, structure

I have a device. It takes commands. I get results and want them to be put into a more usable form.

Example:

`issue_command()` should take a struct as the request and a pointer to a result struct...BUT the structs could be anything I pass. There are around 50 structs over all.

`issue_command(read_request, &result_struct);`

I feel that C can't do this and I couldn't come up with a possible solution (its the only aspect of my program that is not done).

In layman's terms, I want to pass a command struct that is blasted to the device and a result struct paramater that is `memcpy()`'d from the byte result.

Comment: I believe any introductory C++ text would explain how to pass objects to functions. It would also explain how to properly define types.

Comment: I am not passing the SAME types, thats the issue. I know how to pass paramaters...I need multiple types, as each packet has its own structure...

Comment: It's pretty difficult to understand from your question what you're actually asking, could you reword it more clearly? All this `Request: 03 40 30` stuff really isn't relevant, surely you could present a simpler case than that which demonstrates the principle you want.

Comment: In lamemans terms, I want to pass a command struct that is blasted to the device and a result struct paramater that is memcpy'd from the byte result.

Comment: Can you determine from your `read_request` struct what type the `result_struct` should be? If so, have the second parameter as a `void *`, and have `issue_struct` handle the different options accordingly. There are other options, such as unions, if all your different result structs share common initial members.

Comment: So perhaps pass the length of the struct and pass it through a void *. How do I handle the request? The request is basically the packet in a struct.

Comment: In the same way. Somehow, either through a separate parameter or a union, you need to pass sufficient identifying information to the function so it can figure out what to do. Maybe you'd have a constant for each type of request, something like that. If all you're doing is copying bytes in both directions, then the lengths should be sufficient, as you suggest.

Comment: Another idea I had was because all requests are paired with their responses, I could use the returned length and use that for memcpy's length. Then perhaps using a struct with a length + pointer to a request struct that'd handle that portion. If you write a response for the question with a bit more detail on your idea, I'll accept it since it's did help me a lot.

Comment: OK, give me a few minutes.

Comment: set up all those different structs as a union, have the called function expect a pointer to that union,  Then your code has to determine which struct entry in that union is to be referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example program that does what I think you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>


/*  Enumeration, structs, and union for requests  */

enum request_type {
    REQUEST_ONE,
    REQUEST_TWO
};

struct request_one {
    int something;
    char data[10];
};
struct request_two {
    double something_else;
    char data[20];
};

struct request {
    enum request_type type;
    union {
        struct request_one one;
        struct request_two two;
    } request_struct;
};


/*  Enumeration, structs, and union for responses  */

enum response_type {
    RESPONSE_ONE,
    RESPONSE_TWO
};

struct response_one {
    char data[10];
};
struct response_two {
    char data[20];
};

struct response {
    enum response_type type;
    union {
        struct response_one one;
        struct response_two two;
    } response_struct;
};


/*  Constructor functions for request structs  */

struct request * make_request_one(const int something,
                                  char * data) {
    struct request * new_request = malloc(sizeof *new_request);
    if ( !new_request ) {
        perror("Couldn't allocate memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    new_request->type = REQUEST_ONE;
    new_request->request_struct.one.something = something;
    strcpy(new_request->request_struct.one.data, data);

    return new_request;
}

struct request * make_request_two(const double something_else,
                                  char * data) {
    struct request * new_request = malloc(sizeof *new_request);
    if ( !new_request ) {
        perror("Couldn't allocate memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    new_request->type = REQUEST_TWO;
    new_request->request_struct.two.something_else = something_else;
    strcpy(new_request->request_struct.two.data, data);

    return new_request;
}


/*  Constructor functions for response structs  */

struct response * make_response_one(char * data) {
    struct response * new_response = malloc(sizeof *new_response);
    if ( !new_response ) {
        perror("Couldn't allocate memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    new_response->type = RESPONSE_ONE;
    strcpy(new_response->response_struct.one.data, data);

    return new_response;
}

struct response * make_response_two(char * data) {
    struct response * new_response = malloc(sizeof *new_response);
    if ( !new_response ) {
        perror("Couldn't allocate memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    new_response->type = RESPONSE_TWO;
    strcpy(new_response->response_struct.two.data, data);

    return new_response;
}


/*  Issue command function  */

struct response * issue_command(struct request * request) {
    struct response * response;

    switch ( request->type ) {
        case REQUEST_ONE:
            response = make_response_one("resp 1");
            break;

        case REQUEST_TWO:
            response = make_response_two("response 2 stuff");
            break;

        default:
            assert(0);
    }

    return response;
}

int main(void) {

    /*  Call issue_command() with request and response one  */

    struct request * req1 = make_request_one(666, "req 1");
    struct response * resp1 = issue_command(req1);

    printf("Request: %s, Response: %s\n",
           req1->request_struct.one.data,
           resp1->response_struct.one.data);

    free(req1);
    free(resp1);


    /*  Call issue_command() with request and response two  */

    struct request * req2 = make_request_two(3.14159, "request 2 stuff");
    struct response * resp2 = issue_command(req2);

    printf("Request: %s, Response: %s\n",
           req2->request_struct.two.data,
           resp2->response_struct.two.data);

    free(req2);
    free(resp2);

    return 0;
}
```

and outputs:

```
paul@local:~/src/sandbox$ ./reqresp
Request: req 1, Response: resp 1
Request: request 2 stuff, Response: response 2 stuff
paul@local:~/src/sandbox$
```

As you can see, the `issue_command()` function is effectively accepting, with a single input parameter, two different types of struct, and effectively returning, with a single return value, two different types of struct. This is accomplished by wrapping the different structs in a union, in both cases, but you could achieve a similar result through `void` pointers, and actually pass and return completely different structs (rather than single structs containing a union of different structs).

All I'm doing in `issue_command()` is reading the type and constructing an appropriate response, but in the `switch` block, once you've determined which type you have, you can do what you like, access the individual members of the request, or `memcpy()` the whole thing, or whatever. Likewise for the response, once you know what type of request you have, you can read in and fill in the response members however you like.